# SharePoint default modal dialog box not showing buttons

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been doing searches trying to find help on this, but so far all I have found is how to set options for popping up a SharePoint modal dialog box from custom code.

However, I haven't created any custom web parts to display modal dialogs.  What's happening, is if someone clicks the upload document button in a library, the upload document modal dialog comes up, but the ok and cancel buttons are half off of the bottom of the box.  Users can click on them, but it just doesn't look very good.

I started playing with the CSS to make the modal dialog box bigger to reveal the buttons, and that works for the most part, but the real problem is the grant user permission dialog box.

When that is clicked, it doesn't show the ok and cancel buttons, and maximizing the dialog box doesn't reveal them.  The user has to hit tab about 5-10 times before the focus moves to the ok button and is then clickable.

I would post an image, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Has anyone come across this?  It seems very strange that the out of the box setting would have this problem.

The CSS that I use to adjust the height and width of the modal dialog is:
.ms-dlgFrame, .ms-dlgContent, .ms-dlgBorder, .ms-dlgFrameContainer

I'm just trying to set the height/min-height values, but I haven't had much luck.

We're using Internet Explorer 11 to view the pages.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running? Also, are you using a customized masterpage or a stock one?

Comment: i get same issue with "Show more button" in modal dialog of task item. Hope it topic help to you.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7621868-dc2f-463c-939e-0a445aff277e/edit-form-scrollbar-disappears-when-clicking-show-more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stevangelista actually pointed me in the right direction, I wish I could mark comments as answers, and since I'm new I can't upvote the comment, but here's the solution:

I am using a customized master page, and that comment had me take a look at the elements in the page.

Since the master page is being used in the dialog boxes as well, I used the s4-notdlg class to remove parts that weren't needed in the dialogs.  Those parts were pushing the buttons below the bottom of the screen.

I'm not a css expert, so there may be ways of keeping those parts and still have the buttons accessible, but the particular issue I was trying to fix was resolved by using the s4-notdlg class to objects in my custom master page.